XMLDocument splits a line into two when you call SaveToFile
I try to add some attributes to the prolog of an XML-file and I can't find a way to do it other than to insert a complete prolog-string after removing the old prolog
Following example shows what's happens:
const
  XML_Template = 'Invoice_%s.xml';
var
  inv: IXMLInvoiceWood;
  XMLFile: string;
  sl: TStringList;
begin;
  XMLFile := format(XML_Template, ['ABC-123']);
  inv := NewInvoiceWood;
  inv.OwnerDocument.SaveToFile(XMLFile);

  try
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    sl.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);
    sl[0] := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet href="InvoiceWoodV2R31_Build20081207.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>';
    sl.SaveToFile(XMLFile);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;

  inv := LoadInvoiceWood(XMLFile);
  inv.OwnerDocument.SaveToFile(XMLFile); // <<<<--- here it splits the line
  mmo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);

The line splits when save into:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="InvoiceWoodV2R31_Build20081207.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Is this really a problem for you? Because both are valid in XML.

If you say so, it would not be a problem but I'm still curios about it. Why does it split the line when saved?

I cannot reproduce in Delphi 10.3. You should include sample input file and your Delphi version as a tag.  I also don't understand why you use '?' as delimiter in your snippet.

What are you using to open the file  after you have saved it? It could be that is formatting the file for you.

Sorry, the '?' was just that I tested a few things to find  out if there was something I could change. I should have removed that code but missed it. I'll come back soon with a sample file.

Is this reproducible to you also? I mean copy your own code from this website into a new project, run it and also get 2 lines instead of 1? If not then your String literal has a hidden #10 or #13 probably there.

Well, I added some more parts of the code so you can see that I first creates the document adding some attributes and then saves it to a file. After that I loads the file int a stringlist and deletes the original prolog and finally inserts the new prolog.

But now when I want to get a sample of the file it suddenly work ok.  I havn't change anything not even restarted Delphi. I'll try to make a short test program of this code. If I can't reproduce this error I think I have to delete this post or...?

TStringList absolutely does not split strings into extra lines. And given the example shown, there is no way it could possibly know to split a single string between the ?> and <? of 2 consecutive XML instructions. So the issue has to be unrelated to the TStringList itself.

On a side note: sl.Delete(0); sl.Insert(0,'...'); can be simplified to sl[0] := '...';

Ok, I can reproduce it, I was checking a bit to early in the code.

I added a few lines in the code snippet and there you can see where it occurs. So it is the OwnerDocument.SaveToFile - method who's guilty.

Your issue has absolutely nothing to do with TStringList. It's the IXMLDocument behind IXMLInvoiceWood. By default on Windows, that is based on the MSXML COM interface. IUt's being done by that interface when the XML document is saved, and does nothing at all to affect the functionality or validity of the XML. It's actually just a formatting for viewing feature.

This is such a mess. Just make a proper [mcve] already. No wonder you are lost.

Now I have reduced the code to a bare minimum. The problem is that the project uses a unit that is created with "XML DATA BINDING WIZARD" and is huge. The lines split when calling "DOMPersist.save" in unit xml.XMLDoc. Deeper than that is not easy as it is mostly assembly language.

Ken White has given the best answer to this question. Also Mark Rotteveel have a good point on this allthough not explaining the cause of the problem. Anyway, thank's to you all.

Many XML implementations will produce formatted output, unless you specify otherwise. This is normal behavior.
In any case, the correct way to add your extra attributes is to use the XML DOM interfaces to insert them into the Document itself, you do not need to manipulate the XML text after it is generated.  IXMLDocument has Encoding and Version properties, and a CreateNode() method that can create processing instructions (<?...?>), eg:
const
  XML_Template = 'Invoice_%s.xml';
var
  inv: IXMLInvoiceWood;
  XMLFile: string;
  instr: IXMLNode;
begin;
  XMLFile := Format(XML_Template, ['ABC-123']);

  inv := NewInvoiceWood;

  inv.OwnerDocument.Version := '1.0';
  inv.OwnerDocument.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  // or:
  instr := inv.OwnerDocument.CreateNode('xml', ntProcessingInstr, 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"');
  inv.OwnerDocument.ChildNodes.Insert(0, instr);

  instr := inv.OwnerDocument.CreateNode('xml-stylesheet', ntProcessingInstr, 'href="InvoiceWoodV2R31_Build20081207.xsl" type="text/xsl"');

  inv.OwnerDocument.ChildNodes.Add(instr);
  // or:
  with inv.OwnerDocument.ChildNodes do
    Insert(IndexOf(inv.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement), instr);

  ...

  inv.OwnerDocument.SaveToFile(XMLFile);
  mmo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);


The schema for the "InvoiceWood" XML document comes from a system called "Pappinete" and I have checked examples from this system and the "Encoding", "Version" and the string I try to add, is on the prolog-line of the XML-file. But if I use your suggestion the line is placed on the last line of the document. And in the XML-Specification I read that the Prolog must be the first line. So I'm quite confused about this. For the moment I'm not sure how important it is but at least the customer will tell.

Sorry, "Papinet" is the correct name.

I finally solved it.
I added the prolog line after that the complete XML-file was saved using the TStringlist.
const
  XML_Template = 'Invoice_%s.xml';
var
  inv: IXMLInvoiceWood;
  XMLFile: string;
  sl: TStringList;
begin;
  XMLFile := format(XML_Template, ['ABC-123']);
  inv := NewInvoiceWood;

// Compute the xml-file
...
...
// Now save the complete file
  inv.OwnerDocument.SaveToFile(XMLFile);

// Now add the prolog line
  try
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    sl.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);
    sl[0] := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet href="InvoiceWoodV2R31_Build20081207.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>';
    sl.SaveToFile(XMLFile);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;

// Now view the file.
mmo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(XMLFile);

